# saving a file to a specific path

Tags: c#, .net, file, autosave

i have the code for saving a gridview as an html file using a savefiledialog. i want to save it to a specific path (without using the savefiledialog)... how can i do that?

here's my code:

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
dialog.DefaultExt = "*.html";
dialog.Filter = "WORD Document (*.html)|*.html";

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    RadDocument document = CreateDocument(rgvReportData);

    document.LayoutMode = DocumentLayoutMode.Paged;

    document.Measure(RadDocument.MAX_DOCUMENT_SIZE);
    document.Arrange(new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, document.DesiredSize));
    document.SectionDefaultPageMargin = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    document.SectionDefaultPageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

    HtmlFormatProvider provider = new HtmlFormatProvider();

    using (Stream output = dialog.OpenFile())
    {
        provider.Export(document, output);
    }
}
```

how can i sve it without using a savefiledialog?

Answer (score 0):

```
using(StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter("path\to\your\file")) {
     provider.Export(document, output);
}
```

will do the same thing, but to a specific path. You can read more on [file access on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx).

Comment: thank you minitech, but it didn't work. i tried this: using(StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(@"C:\myreport.html")) 
{
 provider.Export(document, output);
} and the error is: cant convert from system.io.streamwriter to system.io.stream. provider.export accepts a document and a stream

Comment: Are you sure? StreamWriter inherits from Stream. You could try an explicit cast, though.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using (var output = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    provider.Export(document, output);
}
```

Comment: thank you ritch, but it didn't work. Export() accepts a Stream as the second parameter.

Comment: @lorane96 - Easy enough. Updated to provide a stream.

Comment: @RitchMelton Can you please tell me why its not saving the data to specific path `string FILE= @"F:\\" + textBox1.Text ;`     `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(FILE + ".txt", contents);`

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = "youfilename.html"; // give the full path if required
    RadDocument document = CreateDocument(rgvReportData);

    document.LayoutMode = DocumentLayoutMode.Paged;

    document.Measure(RadDocument.MAX_DOCUMENT_SIZE);
    document.Arrange(new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, document.DesiredSize));
    document.SectionDefaultPageMargin = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    document.SectionDefaultPageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;

    HtmlFormatProvider provider = new HtmlFormatProvider();

    Stream output = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    provider.Export(document, output);
}
```

Comment: do you see any errors? if so can you mention what errors you see

Answer (score 0):

OpenFileDialog displays the specific path that you have choosen.
You could set the path of the SaveFileDialog, is not necessary to show the dialog like `dialog.ShowDialog()`, you have just to set the path like `dialog.Filename = "file name"`.
And replace it like :

```
SaveFileDialog dialog = new SavefileDialog(); 
dialog.FileName = "path"; // like "C:\\someFolder\\someFile.html"
```

You could try it