# How to get export/ed path of PDF from a Crystal report

Tags: .net, pdf, crystal-reports, export

Hello I want to know the path that the user had saved this pdf export. Is that possible? Here is how I am exporting.

```
FrptSample.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport-English")
```

Normally, the exported document will go to my downloads. But in the case that the user saved in a remote destination, could the path in which he saved in still be known?

If it's impossible to find out were the response saved the pdf, is it possible to manually set a default location, (force download to my downloads)?

Comment: You can't do this through any Crystal Reports API. Even with things like ActiveX or Javascript to do this, the user would have to explicitly allow that control to access their local file system, which is definitely not something you want your users conditioned to say "Yes" to...

Answer (score 0):

By default pdf or any file exporting done in temp folder of your your project directory or iis folder or window temp folder, depend on your application host.

Now you export in particular path, its very easy, just give the path.

one thing is, your application will have access rights to create a file on that folder and accessible that path from hosting place i.e. local machine or in your lan machine.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-export-pdf.htm

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?518197-Export-Crystal-Report

http://asp.net.bigresource.com/Crystal-Reports-Automatically-export-Report-to-PDF-and-save-to-a-remote-location-FTP--fDEXWWv67.html

Alternate option is you can export and then save in file stream too.

[saving a file to a specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066910/saving-a-file-to-a-specific-path)